# R - summary of multi variable regression

Tags: r

I have an R data table, test_data and it looks like this:

```
duration    distance    speed   hincome fi_cost
264 1121    4   1   28
294 1107    4   1   28
111 570 5   1   14
829 2742    3   1   69
181 1111    6   1   28
213 1111    5   1   28
83  445 5   1   11
257 1150    4   1   29
147 812 6   1   20
966 3969    4   1   99
748 3363    4   1   84
```

Im using R to see how fi_cost and hincome explain duration. Thus I am saying:

```
fit <- lm(duration ~ fi_cost + hincome, data=test_data)
```

Resulting in:

```
Call:
lm(formula = duration ~ fi_cost + hincome, data = test_data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2688.0  -287.5   -28.6    93.5  7042.9 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1507.2462    74.2827  20.291  < 2e-16 ***
fi_cost0     -961.7269    75.8125 -12.686  < 2e-16 ***
fi_cost1.5   -200.4032    78.1713  -2.564 0.010400 *  
fi_cost1.7   -258.1474    99.7290  -2.588 0.009680 ** 
fi_cost10    1256.7538   429.9421   2.923 0.003488 ** 
fi_cost10.5  4227.7538   429.9421   9.833  < 2e-16 ***
fi_cost10.8  3204.7538   603.4754   5.310 1.16e-07 ***
fi_cost100  -1128.4962   308.5192  -3.658 0.000258 ***
fi_cost101  -1054.5795   353.6563  -2.982 0.002884 ** 
fi_cost1017   195.7538   603.4754   0.324 0.745672    
fi_cost103  -1035.2462   429.9421  -2.408 0.016097 *  
fi_cost104   -949.2462   238.2346  -3.985 6.90e-05 ***
fi_cost1044   191.7538   603.4754   0.318 0.750694    
fi_cost105  -1035.4128   255.5296  -4.052 5.19e-05 ***
fi_cost106   -934.9962   308.5192  -3.031 0.002459 ** 
fi_cost107   -972.1212   224.3903  -4.332 1.52e-05 ***
fi_cost108   -983.7462   255.5296  -3.850 0.000120 ***
fi_cost109  -1029.2462   429.9421  -2.394 0.016722 *  
fi_cost11   -1443.9962   308.5192  -4.680 2.97e-06 ***
fi_cost11.6  5096.7538   429.9421  11.855  < 2e-16 ***
fi_cost110   -905.4962   308.5192  -2.935 0.003358 ** 
fi_cost111   -914.2462   603.4754  -1.515 0.129871    
fi_cost112   -953.7462   308.5192  -3.091 0.002008 ** 
fi_cost113   -976.7462   308.5192  -3.166 0.001559 ** 
fi_cost114   -937.5795   353.6563  -2.651 0.008059 ** 
fi_cost115   -979.2462   429.9421  -2.278 0.022809 *  
fi_cost116   -936.9962   308.5192  -3.037 0.002407 ** 
fi_cost117   -942.6906   213.0013  -4.426 9.91e-06 ***
fi_cost118   -947.2462   353.6563  -2.678 0.007431 ** 
fi_cost119   -968.6747   238.2346  -4.066 4.89e-05 ***
fi_cost12   -1388.7462   429.9421  -3.230 0.001249 ** 
fi_cost120   -917.4462   277.9404  -3.301 0.000974 ***
fi_cost121   -922.4962   308.5192  -2.990 0.002809 ** 
fi_cost122   -960.4462   277.9404  -3.456 0.000556 ***
fi_cost123   -883.0462   277.9404  -3.177 0.001501 ** 
fi_cost124   -944.5795   353.6563  -2.671 0.007600 ** 
fi_cost125   -815.2462   353.6563  -2.305 0.021214 *  
fi_cost126  -1032.2462   429.9421  -2.401 0.016407 *  
fi_cost129   -781.2462   308.5192  -2.532 0.011377 *  
fi_cost13   -1343.2462   353.6563  -3.798 0.000148 ***
fi_cost13.1  3853.7538   603.4754   6.386 1.93e-10 ***
fi_cost130   -863.0795   255.5296  -3.378 0.000739 ***
fi_cost131   -966.7462   255.5296  -3.783 0.000157 ***
fi_cost132   -961.5795   353.6563  -2.719 0.006581 ** 
fi_cost133   -236.2462   603.4754  -0.391 0.695469    
fi_cost134   -966.5795   353.6563  -2.733 0.006306 ** 
fi_cost135   -906.5795   353.6563  -2.563 0.010405 *  
fi_cost136   -636.2462   429.9421  -1.480 0.139006    
fi_cost137   -922.2462   603.4754  -1.528 0.126548    
fi_cost138   -760.2462   255.5296  -2.975 0.002948 ** 
fi_cost139   -954.2462   429.9421  -2.219 0.026519 *  
fi_cost14   -1436.2462   603.4754  -2.380 0.017368 *  
fi_cost140   -876.5795   255.5296  -3.430 0.000610 ***
fi_cost141   -638.7462   429.9421  -1.486 0.137461    
fi_cost142   -780.7462   429.9421  -1.816 0.069467 .  
fi_cost143   -560.2462   353.6563  -1.584 0.113249    
fi_cost144   -877.2462   277.9404  -3.156 0.001612 ** 
fi_cost145   -864.0462   277.9404  -3.109 0.001894 ** 
fi_cost146   -893.5795   353.6563  -2.527 0.011558 *  
fi_cost147   -882.2462   603.4754  -1.462 0.143847    
fi_cost148  -1032.2462   603.4754  -1.711 0.087262 .  
fi_cost149   -788.2462   353.6563  -2.229 0.025888 *  
fi_cost15   -1408.6462   277.9404  -5.068 4.23e-07 ***
fi_cost150   -771.2462   429.9421  -1.794 0.072926 .  
fi_cost152   -829.9128   353.6563  -2.347 0.018998 *  
fi_cost154   -956.2462   429.9421  -2.224 0.026204 *  
fi_cost155   -777.6462   277.9404  -2.798 0.005172 ** 
fi_cost156   -856.2462   603.4754  -1.419 0.156030    
fi_cost157   -533.7462   308.5192  -1.730 0.083714 .  
fi_cost158   -774.3712   224.3903  -3.451 0.000565 ***
fi_cost159   -754.7462   308.5192  -2.446 0.014480 *  
fi_cost16   -1363.4962   224.3903  -6.076 1.36e-09 ***
fi_cost16.2   952.7538   603.4754   1.579 0.114478    
fi_cost160   -839.5795   353.6563  -2.374 0.017651 *  
fi_cost162   -560.7462   308.5192  -1.818 0.069220 .  
fi_cost163   -779.2462   429.9421  -1.812 0.070004 .  
fi_cost164   -947.2462   603.4754  -1.570 0.116587    
fi_cost165   -784.5795   255.5296  -3.070 0.002154 ** 
fi_cost1659  1019.7538   603.4754   1.690 0.091155 .  
fi_cost166   -808.2462   603.4754  -1.339 0.180554    
fi_cost167   -738.5795   255.5296  -2.890 0.003871 ** 
fi_cost168   -734.5795   353.6563  -2.077 0.037865 *  
fi_cost169   -705.2462   308.5192  -2.286 0.022319 *  
fi_cost17   -1402.2462   603.4754  -2.324 0.020203 *  
fi_cost170   -596.6462   277.9404  -2.147 0.031888 *  
fi_cost171   -904.2462   603.4754  -1.498 0.134121    
fi_cost172   -673.2462   429.9421  -1.566 0.117463    
fi_cost173   -674.7462   429.9421  -1.569 0.116648    
fi_cost175   -378.2462   603.4754  -0.627 0.530845    
fi_cost176   -837.9128   353.6563  -2.369 0.017877 *  
fi_cost177   -575.9128   353.6563  -1.628 0.103519    
fi_cost178   -600.2462   429.9421  -1.396 0.162771    
fi_cost179   -766.2462   255.5296  -2.999 0.002731 ** 
fi_cost18   -1360.2462   353.6563  -3.846 0.000122 ***
fi_cost180   -673.5795   353.6563  -1.905 0.056912 .  
fi_cost182   -592.2462   429.9421  -1.378 0.168446    
fi_cost183   -750.7462   429.9421  -1.746 0.080872 .  
fi_cost184   -724.2462   353.6563  -2.048 0.040646 *  
fi_cost186   -452.2462   603.4754  -0.749 0.453665    
fi_cost188   -409.2462   429.9421  -0.952 0.341232    
fi_cost189   -484.2462   603.4754  -0.802 0.422360    
fi_cost19   -1416.2462   429.9421  -3.294 0.000997 ***
fi_cost190   -675.9128   353.6563  -1.911 0.056059 .  
fi_cost191   -659.5795   353.6563  -1.865 0.062261 .  
fi_cost192   -878.2462   603.4754  -1.455 0.145673    
fi_cost193   -643.2462   429.9421  -1.496 0.134712    
fi_cost195   -603.4962   308.5192  -1.956 0.050533 .  
fi_cost197   -653.5795   353.6563  -1.848 0.064678 .  
fi_cost198   -849.2462   429.9421  -1.975 0.048318 *  
fi_cost2.3    -53.4366   150.3236  -0.355 0.722254    
fi_cost2.4    764.1983   213.0013   3.588 0.000338 ***
fi_cost2.8    669.7538   603.4754   1.110 0.267150    
fi_cost2.9    510.1068   163.1436   3.127 0.001782 ** 
fi_cost20   -1344.0795   255.5296  -5.260 1.53e-07 ***
fi_cost200   -767.2462   353.6563  -2.169 0.030115 *  
fi_cost201   -615.9604   238.2346  -2.586 0.009763 ** 
fi_cost202   -195.2462   603.4754  -0.324 0.746309    
fi_cost204   -525.0462   277.9404  -1.889 0.058967 .  
fi_cost2042  1798.7538   603.4754   2.981 0.002896 ** 
fi_cost205   -711.2462   603.4754  -1.179 0.238645    
fi_cost206   -625.8462   277.9404  -2.252 0.024402 *  
fi_cost207   -871.9128   353.6563  -2.465 0.013733 *  
fi_cost208   -463.9962   308.5192  -1.504 0.132686    
fi_cost2080  1895.7538   603.4754   3.141 0.001696 ** 
fi_cost209   -555.4462   203.4315  -2.730 0.006358 ** 
fi_cost21   -1372.0462   277.9404  -4.936 8.33e-07 ***
fi_cost210   -539.2462   308.5192  -1.748 0.080578 .  
fi_cost2106  1934.7538   603.4754   3.206 0.001358 ** 
fi_cost211   -798.2462   429.9421  -1.857 0.063447 .  
fi_cost213   -587.7462   429.9421  -1.367 0.171702    
fi_cost214   -488.4462   277.9404  -1.757 0.078941 .  
fi_cost2154  1790.7538   603.4754   2.967 0.003024 ** 
fi_cost217   -703.2462   603.4754  -1.165 0.243966    
fi_cost2177  1776.7538   603.4754   2.944 0.003259 ** 
fi_cost218   -556.2462   603.4754  -0.922 0.356729    
fi_cost219   -692.2462   429.9421  -1.610 0.107469    
fi_cost22   -1380.2462   429.9421  -3.210 0.001338 ** 
fi_cost220   -413.7462   429.9421  -0.962 0.335951    
fi_cost221   -745.2462   603.4754  -1.235 0.216942    
fi_cost222   -197.2462   429.9421  -0.459 0.646425    
fi_cost223   -437.2462   429.9421  -1.017 0.309230    
fi_cost225   -280.2462   603.4754  -0.464 0.642400    
fi_cost226   -842.2462   603.4754  -1.396 0.162906    
fi_cost227   -625.2462   429.9421  -1.454 0.145965    
fi_cost228   -717.7462   429.9421  -1.669 0.095128 .  
fi_cost229   -727.2462   429.9421  -1.691 0.090831 .  
fi_cost2294  2133.7538   429.9421   4.963 7.28e-07 ***
fi_cost23   -1382.2462   277.9404  -4.973 6.90e-07 ***
fi_cost230   -693.2462   603.4754  -1.149 0.250735    
fi_cost232   -754.2462   603.4754  -1.250 0.211443    
fi_cost236   -451.2462   308.5192  -1.463 0.143662    
fi_cost2368  2449.7538   429.9421   5.698 1.31e-08 ***
```

and so on and so on....

When I carried this out before I got this as a summary:

```
lm(formula = duration ~ fi_cost + hincome, data=test_data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-36.027  -1.581  -0.371   1.023  13.713

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      6.543e+00  5.786e-02 113.083   <2e-16 ***
fi_cost          4.359e-03  8.773e-05  49.686   <2e-16 ***
hincome          7.090e-02  8.362e-03   8.479   <2e-16 ***
fi_cost:hincome -1.024e-04  1.174e-05  -8.722   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.58 on 18926 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5223,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5222
F-statistic:  6897 on 3 and 18926 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Why am I getting this disaggregation of fi_cost? Have an issue with the data? The call to R is the same. Have I changed a setting for what 'summary' displays?

Edit

```
str(test_data)

'data.frame':   2129 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ duration: int  264 294 111 829 181 213 83 257 147 966 ...
 $ distance: int  1121 1107 570 2742 1111 1111 445 1150 812 3969 ...
 $ speed   : Factor w/ 25 levels "\\N","1","10",..: 20 20 21 19 22 21 21 20 22 20 ...
 $ hincome : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ fi_cost : Factor w/ 307 levels "\\N","0","1",..: 132 132 46 263 132 132 16 137 90 307 ...
>
```

Comment: did you mix up anova(fit) with summary(fit) ?

Comment: Can you post a `str(test_data)`.

Comment: `fi_cost` is a factor! Eventually you want to convert it `as.numeric(...)`

Comment: Ah! Now, what does that mean? Im googling...

Comment: What does fi_cost stand for and what kind of data is it?

Comment: It should be an integer. I exported these csv's from mysql and Ive just found the rogue data - I have a few "\N" in there!

Comment: They have caused R to format it as a Factor. Feel free to post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `fi_cost` is a factor! Eventually you want to convert it with `as.numeric(...)`. Because of some strange "\N" you have to replace them or to go back to reading your data. In `read.table()` (and similar) you can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or `as.is=TRUE` to preventing the conversion to factors.

**Mandatory:** after reading the data check it with `str(...)`